# When select an spinner item, selecteditem changes to first item

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter

i've implemented a spinner with custom adapter.
When i select any item of this spinner, it will cause to disappear from the spinners list.
The position gets overridden by the first item of the list, making in appear double.
e.g:

Click on spinner:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3 <-- Select Item 3

Reopen spinner:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- **Item 1**

Does somebody know, why the postion gets overridden and how to avoid that?

```
public class activityScheduler extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

   Spinner spinner;
   Adapter.spinner.spinAdapterActuator componentActuator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

        spinner =  findViewById(R.id.spinner_sensors);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Actuator i = componentActuator.getActuator(position);        
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        Update();

         }
      });
    }

    public void Update() {

        ArrayList<Actuator> components = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Actuator> componentList = allOperationList();
        item = new Actuator();

        for (int i=0; i < componentList.size(); i++)
        {
            item = componentList.get(i);
            components.add(item);
            Log.d(componentList.size() + "",item.name);
        }

        componentActuator = new spinner.spinAdapterActuator(activityMain.getContextOfApplication(),components);
        spinner.setAdapter(componentActuator);
        componentActuator.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
  public List<Actuator> allOperationList (){
        return new Select()
                .from(Actuator.class)
                .execute();
    }
}

// And the adapter

 public static class spinAdapterActuator extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        private ArrayList<Actuator> arrayList;

        public spinAdapterActuator (Context context, ArrayList<Actuator> arrayList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        public Actuator getActuator(int position) {
            return arrayList.get(position);
        }

        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = View.inflate(context,R.layout.spinner_scheduler, null);

                ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_component);

                Actuator item = arrayList.get(position);
                name.setText(item.getDescription());
                icon.setImageResource(Converter.toImg(item.getName(),1));
            }
            return convertView;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Time to learn how to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked the issue myself, the issue is that I used the getview method in wrong way:

```
if(convertView == null){
                convertView = View.inflate(context,R.layout.spinner_scheduler, null);
                ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_component);
                name.setText(item.getDescription());
                icon.setImageResource(Converter.toImg(item.getName(),1));    
            }
            return convertView;
```

Should be

```
if(convertView == null){
                convertView = View.inflate(context,R.layout.spinner_scheduler, null);          
            }
ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_component);
                name.setText(item.getDescription());
                icon.setImageResource(Converter.toImg(item.getName(),1));   
            return convertView;
```